# Nvidia Nsight connection to localhost failed

Tags: connection, localhost, nvidia, nsight

After many hours working on this trouble, I ask for help here.

I installed the latest Nvidia Nsight VS Edition 4.2 and I'm not able to connect to the localhost for local debugging. I always got this error:

> //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>
> Nsight Debug:
>
> Connection to the Nsight monitor on 'localhost' failed.  Please make sure the monitor is running on > the target machine and the security settings match.
>
> //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

The Nsight Monitor is running and it shows a green ball in the configuration page. Connections: no connections (clearly).

In the options, I set port 8000 for both the Monitor and the Nsight VS Options. 
For the security tab, I set False for the Enable secure connection.

I'm on a Windows 8.1 machine, tried for both VS2012 and VS2013 without success.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I notice you are trying to connect to 'localhost', which means you are trying to launch your sample on the same machine as your Visual Studio with Nsight runs on. Hard to say why, but please try these:

- close Monitor, and begin your debug session in Visual Studio, Nsight will launch the monitor automatically
- try to restore the options to default in both Nsight and Monitor, since I'm not sure what else options you have set which may affect the connection. If this still not work, try to adjust `8000` port number to some number else
- Since you are on `Win8.1`, do you add Nsight Monitor to white list of your firewall?
- Try to launch Visual Studio and Monitor in both admin privilege.

Since I don't know very detail about your configuration, but I do hope show you some help, especially add Monitor to firewall and run as admin privilege, it's a hint from my experience.

Thanks
An

Comment: Thank you for your support, but I tried all your suggestions without success. I wonder I'd find something different to debug my graphics.

Comment: That's weird, actually I have a Win8.1 OS also, I can do debug smoothly without any special settings. Maybe you can try to remove these configuration files, and check what will happen: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight\Vsip\1.0\PersistedItems\`. Do remember to backup this, ;)